# Multi value parameter in paginated reports (in single parameter)

Tags: powerbi-paginated-reports

I am looking to implement multi value parameter in paginated reports for a sql server connection. The values just generate for 1st value not for others.

I have tried all possible ways join, split string, nothing works.

Can someone point me in correct direction?

Or a blog, video, step guide.

Thanks